# C++ Sorting Array. Why need other sort method?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting

**--------Adding 4/27/2015**
I think I get some idea from @Ulrich Eckhardt. And thanks all for replying.

**Question**: for sorting array, why not directly use sort(), what algorithm in sort()?

Remember when I was studying at school, professor gave us C++ homework about sorting an array. We use lots of time, and we thought something crazy that could do "A[]=B[]" or "A.size()"**[just clarify we could not do those things in array]**. Then our professor taught us sorting algorithm. Sorting array became something like this:(quickSort for example)

```
void quickSort(int arr[], int left, int right) {
      int i = left, j = right;
      int tmp;
      int pivot = arr[(left + right) / 2];

      /* partition */
      while (i <= j) {
            while (arr[i] < pivot)
                  i++;
            while (arr[j] > pivot)
                  j--;
            if (i <= j) {
                  tmp = arr[i];
                  arr[i] = arr[j];
                  arr[j] = tmp;
                  i++;
                  j--;
            }
      };

      /* recursion */
      if (left < j)
            quickSort(arr, left, j);
      if (i < right)
            quickSort(arr, i, right);
}
```

When I saw the **sort()** I was sharked. Actually life could be so simple.
**Question**: for sorting array, why not directly use sort(). What is sort()? and what algorithm in sort()? how to implement sort()?

**-----------------------Adding 4/27/2015**

Just wondering, for **sorting array**. We have "sort" method already in algorithm library, and why we still need all kinds of other sorting method (like quick sort, merge sort, bubble sort...) to sort array? Does that cost less time? The code for sorting array is like below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
int main()
{int array[]={23, 5, -10, 0, 0, 321, 1, 2, 99, 30};
 int elements =sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
   std::sort(array, array + elements);
 for(int i =0; i < elements;++i)   
   std::cout<< array[i]<<' ';
}
```

Also could sort strings:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm> 
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{  string array[] = { "s", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "f", "b", "sg" }; 
int elements = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]); 
std::sort(array, array + elements); 
for (int i = 0; i < elements; ++i)  
std::cout << array[i] << ' ';
}
```

Thanks all for taking time answering.

Comment: `std::sort` specifies an *interface*, but needs to implement some sorting algorithm (e.g., introsort).

Comment: `std::sort()` is not a method but a plain function (a function template, if you want). Quick sort, merge sort and others are algorithms, not functions. They are like the idea behind some function rather than the code itself.

Comment: I feel like your question would be much more meaningful if you added some *context*.

Comment: For such small arrays, you shouldn't care about speed. For mid-sized arrays, the standard algorithms will do fine. For larger arrays, your thinking must be recast in a larger context and you first should question why you need to sort.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it probably belongs on either programmers or computer science

Answer (score 4):

`std::sort` also uses some `comparison sort algorithm`. And different algorithms have different usages. Best example: `Bead sort`. This algorithm has a pretty good runtime complexity. But it can only be used for unsigned integers. Every algorithm has its own flaws and strengthes.

Answer (score 1):

No doubt quick sort `sort()`and merge sort `stable_sort()` are the fastest but there are factors such as whether given order of the elements in container is `random`,`nearly sorted`, `reversed` or it contains duplicate values.
Combine these factors with one more factor that is number of elements to be sorted gives you the idea why we might need different sorting algos.

Sorting algos are invented one after the other and every newly discovered sorting algo was required to be faster than previous one to get accepted.

To get the mist clear on algos' runtime you can refer to:
http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/

---

I hope that helped. Comment for further clarification.

Answer (score -1):

The built in algorithm library isn't enough to sort data. It needs a backbone, which is the algorithm(Merge/Bubble/Heap) and code.

Comment: "The built in algorithm library isn't enough to sort data": what do you mean ? The <algorithm> library is self contained and supplies all the required sorting algorithms.